# mvn site failed when I add maven-javadoc-plugin

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin

I add this to my pom.xml

```
 `  <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>`
```

In order to create javadocs. Before that "mvn site" ran perfectly . After I add this to my pom I get this.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] autotest_drivers .................................. FAILURE [7.516s]
[INFO] autotest_driver_vm_controller_so .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_machine_manager ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_web_driver ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_traffic_generators ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_gui_is ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_smart_console ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_management_client ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] autotest_driver_traffic ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7.853s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Aug 06 09:29:15 IDT 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 51M/889M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project autotest_drivers: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I add it to my other projects everything worked great.
I'm sorry I can't post more information.

add mvn site -X as requested. It seems odd all of this dependencies are outside of my project.

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project autotest_drivers: Error during page generation: Error rendering Maven report: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0:site (default-site) on project autotest_drivers: Error during page generation
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error during page generation
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:143)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.RendererException: Error rendering Maven report: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:233)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.getClasspath(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2598)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.addJavadocOptions(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:4582)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.executeReport(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2028)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.JavadocReport.generate(JavadocReport.java:130)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:228)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven30DependencyResolverException: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven30DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven30DependencyResolver.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven30DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven30DependencyResolver.java:204)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.javadoc.AbstractJavadocMojo.getClasspath(AbstractJavadocMojo.java:2579)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemCore:jar:6.1.01, javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4, javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1, org.springframework:spring:jar:2.0, org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.7.0, org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.7.0, commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.0.1, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1, xalan:serializer:jar:2.7.1, jython:jython:jar:2.1, jfree:jfreechart:jar:1.0.13, jfree:jcommon:jar:1.0.16, commons-jxpath:commons-jxpath:jar:1.3, com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.9.2, il.co.topq.difido:difido-reports-common:jar:0.5-SNAPSHOT, org.jsystemtest:jsystem-launcher:jar:6.1.01, asm:asm:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-commons:jar:2.2.3, asm:asm-tree:jar:2.2.3, org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4, org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0, commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.3, xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.4.01, com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.7, xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1, xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c, com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4, net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:jar:2.10, org.jdom:jdom2:jar:2.0.5, org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.8.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.1, com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.7.1, org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.15, org.apache.poi:poi:jar:3.11, commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9, joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.4, commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1, dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1, com.vmware:vijava:jar:5.1, org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.10, org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.4, org.jsystemtest:jsystemApp:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest:jsystemAgent:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:FileTransfer:jar:6.1.01, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:cli:jar:6.1.01, ch.ethz.ganymed:ganymed-ssh2:jar:build210, javax.comm:comm:jar:1.0, tftp4java:tftp4java-server:jar:0.8, tftp4java:tftp4java-client:jar:0.8, org.apache.ftpserver:ftpserver-core:jar:dev, org.jsystemtest.systemobjects:embeddedCatalina:jar:6.1.01, tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, commons-modeler:commons-modeler:jar:2.0, commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.2, commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.0.4, mx4j:mx4j-jmx:jar:2.1.1, com.jgoodies:looks:jar:2.2.2, net.javaprog.jwizz:jwizz:jar:0.1.3, org.swinglabs:swingx:jar:1.6.1, com.jhlabs:filters:jar:2.0.235, org.swinglabs:swing-worker:jar:1.1, log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15, junit:junit:jar:4.4, org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1, commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6, org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1, org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.12, org.aspectj:aspectjtools:jar:1.6.12: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:538)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifacts(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:397)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.dependencies.resolve.internal.Maven30DependencyResolver.resolveDependencies(Maven30DependencyResolver.java:226)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:669)
    at org.sonatype.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.resourceExists(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:623)
    at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$GetTask.run(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:577)
    ... 4 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Execute with -X to get a verbose report and please append the results

Comment: Tell me if this is ok ? really lost here.

Comment: Is org.jsystemtest from your package structure?

Comment: There are two things. First the error you get: `from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.` meaning your are behind a proxy/firewall which you are not allowed to go through and furthermore you should use a more recent version of the maven-site-plugin cause the version 3.0 is six years old..better use version 3.6 the most recent version...

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.jsystemtest:jsystemCommon:jar:6.1.01 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Not authorized, ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized.
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:951)
at org.sonatype.aether.connector.wagon.WagonRepositoryConnector$4.wrap(WagonRepositoryConnector.java:941)
```

It is failing when it tries to write the generated artifact to wherever you have specified they should be placed.

Comment: Strange. what even more strange that mvn works fine now... I will look in to it.